# Setting frame rate of segmented webm in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, framerate

I'm using ffmpeg to segment files for use in MSE. I've tried dozens of combinations of flags. No matter what I always get a frame rate that can't possibly be right, specifically 1k frames per second. Here's what I see when I inspect one of the resulting segments.

`ffmpeg -i test000.webm`

`Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'test000.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1047 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9,`**1k fps**`, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)`

By the way, my source, my original, unsegmented webm file shows the fps as 29.97.

Why does it do this and how do I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: If the file plays right, don't worry about it. The `tbr` is the rate ffmpeg will assume when converting the file.

Comment: This is related to an effort to play segments in MSE, which is currently not working. Someone suggested to me this might be a contributing factor. I won't bore with the details, but I am interested in eliminating this as a possible factor.